# All that glitters is gold

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, visual

So, Mom visited my place today and heard that I have been puzzling after a long long time. She said she was happy to know that I am back at doing what I love doing.

While having her cup of coffee, she was listening to her all time favorite Bob Marley, when I told her how my puzzles were getting solved quickly and that I am really looking forward to setting a harder one this time. 30 odd seconds into the song and she started scribbling something on a piece of paper.

Now, I know my Mom has been a puzzler herself, I was intrigued on learning what she was doing. She finished her coffee, took her stick, stood up, gave me a piece of paper and walked away. It had some gibberish letters and a box at front and a little note at the back -

> *Follow the music,*
> *Move like a King,*
> *Exceptions are low.*
> *Will guide you to something I want you to know.*

Here's what the piece of paper had. It's all gibberish to me.

[image]

Here's a text version if it helps -

> UDTKNHGIFOONBOTEETYWYWWONHPNOHATDEUEKITRELFIVHTHPDILSIREAINIRGTEANSUNENOVETTNALPDAESDOILUDELLGNYWANHMHCATOTSERAHMRGUP♪PEERTHET

***Can you please help me find what she wants me to know?***

Comment: ♪ instead of the emoji, maybe?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your Mom’s message to you is...

> **IT IS OK**.

Continuing from @M Oehm’s answer...

> The cluephrase BEYOND PLAIN SIGHT clues using braille. If we look at the positions of the unused letters (the ones read out to obtain the cluephrase) and interpret them as braille, we can read out the answer **IT IS OK**.

Comment: Great job!!! :)

Answer (score 19):

Your mom is telling you to look ...

> ... **beyond plain sight**.

The first step ...

> ... is to rearrange the letters in the given 9×14 grid:
>
> ```
>      U D T K N H G I F
>      O O N B O T E E T
>      Y W Y W W O N H P
>      N O H A T D E U E
>      K I T R E L F I V
>      H T H P D I L S I
>      R E A I N I R G T
>      E A N S U N E N O
>      V E T T N A L P D
>      A E S D O I L U D
>      E L L G N Y W A N
>      H M H C A T O T S
>      E R A H M R G U P
>      * P E E R T H E T
> ```

Then ...

> ... we can "follow the music", i.e. start where the note is and "move like a king", i.e. move like a Chess king to adjacent fields in any of the eight directions. If we do that, we can trace the following course:
>
>  [image: Get up, stand up, ...]
>
>  It follows the lyrics of Bob Marley's song "Get Up, Stand Up", beginning about 30 seconds into the song: "Preacher man don't tell me heaven is under the earth. I know you don't know what life is really worth. [...] Get up, stand up, Don't give up the fight."
>
>  The unused letters spell: "Beyond plain sight".

Comment: Beat me to it! (You missed the "H" in "fight" in the top row btw)

Comment: rot13(Gur cuenfr ORLBAQ CYNVA FVTUG pyhrf oenvyyr, fb gur hahfrq yrggref pna or qrpbqrq nf oenvyyr gb trg gur svany nafjre VG VF BX.)

Comment: @Techidiot: Ah, I suspected as much, but not enough to mark it a partial answer.

Comment: @SeptaCube: Oh, that's clever. If you like, you can wrap this one up in a separate answer.

Comment: Typo: the grid is size 9x14 and not 9x13. (I think I could just edit that but I'm not sure)